# Deleting 'this' object from Cart in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Cart Controller (used single resource as no id needed) which in the show action can have multiple objects (Images in this example), each Image that was added to the basket is listed, but as a user I might want to change my mind at this point and remove an Image.

I'm not sure if my current implementation has caused me issues but I am looking for a way to say "Delete this Image".

This is what I have so far

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  # photo
end

create_table "images", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "description"
  t.string   "photo_file_name"
  t.string   "photo_content_type"
  t.integer  "photo_file_size"
  t.datetime "photo_updated_at"
  t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
end

class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  # user_id, image_id
end

create_table "carts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "image_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

When adding an Image to the cart I do this via a `button_to` with Ajax

```
<%= button_to cart_path(image_id: params[:id], user_id: current_or_guest_user), method: :post, :remote => true %>
```

When viewing the Images in the cart I use the show action of the cart

```
class CartController < ApplicationController
  def show
    cart_ids = Cart.where(user_id: current_or_guest_user)
    image_ids = cart_ids.map(&:image_id)
    @cart_images = Image.where(id: image_ids)
  end
end
```

View

```
<% @cart_images.each do |i| %>
  <%= button_to cart_path(id: # unsure here), method: :delete, :remote => true %>
<% end %>
```

How can I get the corresponding Cart Id for the image that I am about to delete

Would a relation like Image has_many Carts work here ? or in fact the other way around so a Cart has_many Images, and once I have added an image to a cart have a after_create action to update the image with the cart id? or is that completely wrong ?

Comment: Can you please show your DB schema for the relative models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since images have no back-reference to the cart (the foreign key resides in the Cart table), it may be best to approach your situation this way:

In your controller:

```
# Get the cars for the current user that DO have an image associated
@carts_with_images = Cart.where(user_id: current_or_guest_user).where.not(image_id: nil)
```

Then in your view:

```
<% @carts_with_images.each do |cart| %>
  <%= button_to cart_path(cart), method: :delete, remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

You can then just as easily access the cart's image in the loop by using `cart.image`

Comment: Thanks Wes, so would this approach be better than say having the foreign  key the other way around, so a cart having many images? or am i thinking about that incorrectly ?

Comment: Without knowing your exact intentions, it's hard to say which would be better for your app. But based on what you already have, my suggestion would be the best (and probably only) way to have both the `cart` and `image` objects accessible within the same loop in the view

Comment: actually, upon closer inspection your solution seems much cleaner :-) thank you

Comment: sorry another question, to use cart.image, do i need a relationship setup? if i use `cart.image.photo(:large)` for example i get `undefined method `image' for #<Cart:`

Comment: Yes, the `Cart` object should `belongs_to: :image` -- This "sounds" odd, which is probably a sign that your model's schema is probably wrong. But you know your app better than I do. Putting the foreign key in the `image` model would require the association `Image` `belongs_to: :cart`, which sounds better, and also may be the direction you want to go.